# the property of the my project is configured right , but visual studio still can not open include header file

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, preprocessor

everyone , Sorry if this is such a naive question,but it really disrupts me .

I am using boost library in my project.

I think my project is configured right , in the properties of the project , in the additional include directories part :
I have provided :D:\work material\LIBRARY\BOOST2\x64\include\boost-1_71
I also provided the lib path in the linker part ..

my corresponding  source code is :

```
#ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
#  include <stdint.h>
#else
#  include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

typedef boost::int64_t    int64_t;
typedef boost::uint64_t  uint64_t;
typedef boost::int32_t    int32_t;
typedef boost::uint32_t  uint32_t;
typedef boost::int16_t    int16_t;
typedef boost::uint16_t  uint16_t;
typedef boost::int8_t      int8_t;
typedef boost::uint8_t    uint8_t;
#endif
```

the macro HAVE_STDINT_H is not defined .
and when compiled ,I get the error:

**Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'boost/cstdint.hpp': No such file or directory**

I  have compiled successfully before ,but this time it seems never will work .

Answer (score 0):

sorry ,guys and gals. it is  a naive  question,indeed . It turns out that another project on which this project depend doesn't have the right configuration.
As I mentioned ,it successes before ,so follow pure logic ,I should try to pin down the problem in other directions .But it is a time constrained work ,I want to finish it as soon as possible ,So post it on stack overflow.